# Shock when a supernova explodes

Tags: astrophysics, shock-waves, supernova, cosmic-rays

I have been reading that when supernovae explode, they produce (Shockwaves) which act as cosmic accelerators.

I do not understand, what is meant with "shock" (partially because I do not study in English), or how it is produced when the supernova explodes, could someone elaborate?

I would also be interested in the mechanism of how these shock "accelerate" particles? As well as if good resources are linked in which this subject is explained well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_acceleration

Comment: It's important to remember that "empty space" is not truly empty. There's always some stuff in so-called "empty space", particularly so in the vicinity of nascent supernova as the star has likely shed a good amount of material prior to going supernova. That means that there's a fluid medium around that star that supports sound, at least to some extent, which in turn means shockwaves are possible. I would have answered similarly if @KyleKanos hadn't beat me to the punch. His answer is excellent.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76852/59023, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/349711/59023, and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131812/59023

Comment: When anything explodes, that by definition produces a shock… in broad lay terms, that's the difference between 'explosion' and mere 'combustion' or if you like, 'burning.'

In broad terms, 'explosion' is instantaneous but 'combustion' or 'burning' take incomparably longer.

For instance, gunpowder instantaneously explodes into 40,000 times its initial volume. (Who doubts that, ask any encyclopedia or search engine…)

FYI, tests show petrol to be 300 times more explosive than gunpowder, which is why your car works as it does…

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A [shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) is when a fluid flow moves much faster than the speed of sound of the medium. With [supernovae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova), the material that was once the star (e.g., hydrogen, helium, etc) is pushed outwards with such great force that it travels at a few percent of the speed of light! As the [speed of sound of the interstellar medium (ISM) is about 10 km/s](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/162259/25301), a velocity of ~30,000 km/s is definitely going generate a shock.

As the supernova ejecta expands, it begins sweeping up material from the ISM, which does slow it down, though over the course of many thousands of years. This is the material that is accelerated via what is called [*diffusive shock acceleration*](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9711177) (arXiv link) or, equivalently, [second-order Fermi mechanism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/231314/25301) and become the 'cosmic rays' we observe regularly.

The general idea of the mechanism is that at the shock front, a particle (proton, alpha, etc) from the ambient ISM scatters off the tangled magnetic field at the shock interface and can repeatedly cross the shock front. From the [jump conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions) between the two states, a particle can gain a very small energy, $E_{i+1}=(1+\alpha)E_{i}$ where $\alpha\propto u_1-u_2$ where the $u_i$ are the velocity of the 'upstream' (1) and 'downstream' (2) regions.
Now the interesting thing is that this gain of energy occurs when the particle crosses *from either direction*!

Thus, after $k$ crossings, the particle has gained an energy of
$$E_k=(1+\alpha)^kE_0.$$
After each crossing, the particle has a return probability of, $P_\text{return}=1-\rho_1u_2/\rho_2$. Then after $k$ crossings, the number of particles remaining would be
$$N_k=N_0P_\text{return}^k\equiv N_0\left(1-P_\text{escape}\right)^k.$$
Since the $k$ in both the previous two equations are the same, we can solve for it to find that,
$$\frac{\log(N_k/N_0)}{1-P_\text{escape}}=\frac{\log(E_k/E_0)}{\log(1+\alpha)}\implies N(E)\sim N_0\left(\frac{E}{E_0}\right)^s.$$
This is consistent with the power-law distribution we observe in cosmic rays (see [Matthiae 2010](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/12/7/075009), for instance).

When modeling this, one utilizes the aforementioned diffusive shock acceleration framework in which a particle distribution, $f(\mathbf{x},\,\mathsf{p},\,t)$ with $\mathsf{p}$ the particle momenta, evolves as,
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla f=\nabla\cdot\left(D\nabla f\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}\right)\mathsf{p}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\mathsf{p}}+\mathcal{S}$$
where $\mathbf{u}$ is the fluid velocity and $\mathcal{S}$ the source gain/loss term. We can integrate this distribution to obtain a pressure term,
$$p_\text{cr}(\mathbf{x}\,t)\sim\int\,\frac{\mathsf{p}^4}{\sqrt{1+\mathsf{p}^2}}f(\mathbf{x},\,\mathsf{p},\,t)\,\mathrm{d}\mathsf{p}.$$
This pressure must be accounted for in the dynamic evolution of the supernova remnant:
\begin{align}
\partial_t\rho+\nabla\cdot(\rho\mathbf{u}) &= 0 \\
\partial_t(\rho\mathbf{u})+\nabla\cdot\left(\rho\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}+p_\text{total}\mathbf{I}\right) &= -\nabla p_\text{cr} \\
\partial_tE+\nabla\cdot\left(\mathbf{u}\left(E+p_\text{total}\right)\right)&=-\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla p_\text{cr}
\end{align}
(though one probably should include the magnetic fields in the above hydrodynamic equations).

For a good treatment, [Kirk's *Plasma Astrophysics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-31627-2) covers this well. At research-level, pretty much anything by Tom Jones, Don Ellison, Pasquale Blasi or Damiano Caprioli on the subject is going to be what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not just the speed of sound. Any interaction that exceeds the speed of some wave phenomenon in a fluid can result in a shock. Water skiers (and also dolphins) take advantage of the fact that boats easily exceed the speed at which water surface waves propagate. That's a nit, plus one. Your answer also saved me from taking the time to write up an answer, so if I could, plus one again. And plus one yet again for a very nice writeup. Unfortunately, you can only get one plus one from me.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great and well supported explanation !

Comment: Another terrestrial analogy is a sonic boom, right?

Comment: @Barmar The sonic boom is what we would hear as a result of an object having broken the sound barrier, but yes that is probably close enough to accurate.

Comment: Cool downvote ಠ__ಠ